# How to group_by data.frame by both groups and order?

Tags: r, group-by

Imagine a person uses a phone randomly, and the use time is recorded.

```r
# Let's make a data.frame first. 
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
my_data <- data.frame(
  name = c(rep("Lily", 6), rep("Sam", 4)), 
  log_order = c(1:6, 1:4), 
  place = c(
    rep("home", 2), rep("school", 2), rep("home", 2), 
    rep("school", 2), rep("home", 2)
  ), 
  use_time = sample(1:10, 10)
)
my_data
# name log_order  place use_time
# 1  Lily         1   home       10
# 2  Lily         2   home        6
# 3  Lily         3 school        5
# 4  Lily         4 school        4
# 5  Lily         5   home        1
# 6  Lily         6   home        8
# 7   Sam         1 school        2
# 8   Sam         2 school        7
# 9   Sam         3   home        9
# 10  Sam         4   home        3
# In this case: 
# For the first time, Lily stayed at home and used the phone for 10 minutes. 
# For the second time, Lily used for 6 minutes, still at home. 
# For the third time, Lily used the phone for 5 minutes at school. 
# And another 4 minutes at school. 
# Then went back home and used the phone twice, for 1 and 8 min respectively.
```

What I want to calculate, is the total use time of each person in each period by the different places. In this case, Lily has three "periods"s by place, the first and third one is at school and the second one is at home; while Sam has two periods, the first is at school and the second is at home. The desired result is as follows.

```r
# Allow me to make a middle result manually first. 
my_data_period <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(period = c(
    1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    1, 1, 2, 2
  ))
my_data_period
# name log_order  place use_time period
# 1  Lily         1   home       10      1
# 2  Lily         2   home        6      1
# 3  Lily         3 school        5      2
# 4  Lily         4 school        4      2
# 5  Lily         5   home        1      3
# 6  Lily         6   home        8      3
# 7   Sam         1 school        2      1
# 8   Sam         2 school        7      1
# 9   Sam         3   home        9      2
# 10  Sam         4   home        3      2

# The expected result. 
my_data_period %>% 
  group_by(name, period, place) %>% 
  summarise(tot_use_time = sum(use_time)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-period)
# name  place  tot_use_time
# <chr> <chr>         <int>
# 1 Lily  home             16
# 2 Lily  school            9
# 3 Lily  home              9
# 4 Sam   school            9
# 5 Sam   home             12
```

How can I get that expected result from "my_data" directly without the manual coding process?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "How can I get that expected result from "my_data" directly without the manual coding process?". Does this answer your question?

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
set.seed(1234)
my_data <- data.frame(
  name = c(rep("Lily", 6), rep("Sam", 4)), 
  log_order = c(1:6, 1:4), 
  place = c(
    rep("home", 2), rep("school", 2), rep("home", 2), 
    rep("school", 2), rep("home", 2)
  ), 
  use_time = sample(1:10, 10)
)
my_data
#>    name log_order  place use_time
#> 1  Lily         1   home       10
#> 2  Lily         2   home        6
#> 3  Lily         3 school        5
#> 4  Lily         4 school        4
#> 5  Lily         5   home        1
#> 6  Lily         6   home        8
#> 7   Sam         1 school        2
#> 8   Sam         2 school        7
#> 9   Sam         3   home        9
#> 10  Sam         4   home        3

my_data %>%
  group_by(name, period = cumsum(place != lag(place, default = first(place))), place) %>%
  summarise(tot_use_time = sum(use_time), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(-period)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   name  place  tot_use_time
#>   <chr> <chr>         <int>
#> 1 Lily  home             16
#> 2 Lily  school            9
#> 3 Lily  home              9
#> 4 Sam   school            9
#> 5 Sam   home             12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Beat me by 57 secs.

Comment: I think @Mark beat me to it by 2min (+1) but had to make some edits

Comment: And you can use `.groups = "drop"` in `summarise`, no need for an extra call to `ungroup`.

Comment: yes I got a bit confused, thought `my_data_period` was the desired result haha

Answer (score 1):

```
my_data |>
  mutate(period = cumsum(place != lag(place, default = "")), .by = name) |> 
  summarise(tot_use_time = sum(use_time), .by = c(name, period, place)) |> 
  select(-period)
```